# Formatting JSON Google Vision OCR Language Hints

Tags: json, ocr

JSON formatting is a weakness of mine, and I am running a script that is submitting json requests to google vision API for OCR on images. The results are poor, so I think I may need to add Language Hints. Here is the basic json call:

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "image": {
        "source": {
          "gcsImageUri": "gs://YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/YOUR_FILE_NAME"
        }
      },
      "features": [
        {
          "type": "TEXT_DETECTION"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

[Here is the page showing Language Hints.](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate#imagecontext) How can i add it to the json code in a valid way. I keep getting syntax errors!!

Answer (score 2):

In case there are others who stumble on this question. This is the request for English and Chinese.

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "image": {
        "source": {
          "gcsImageUri": "gs://YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/YOUR_FILE_NAME"
        }
      },
      "features": [
        {
          "type": "TEXT_DETECTION"
        }
      ],
      "imageContext": {
        "languageHints": [
          "en", "zh"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Languages can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/languages.